# how to make kendo grid vertical scrollbar appear when the grid exceeds 10 rows

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, scrollbar

i have a kendo grid that may have 1000 rows. but i want my grid to show scrollbar after 10 rows. And scroll sholud always point to the last row of the grid.

Comment: [This doesn't works for you?](http://dojo.telerik.com/IHiQo)

Answer (score 0):

Just put some height on it and set scrollable enable true.
.Scrollable(s => s.Height(250))
.Scrollable(s => s.Enabled(true)

The height will depend on the default number of rows you are setting 
.PageSize(10)

Comment: scrollable is enabled by default, so that second `Enabled(true)` is unnecessary. If you still wanted it you could clean up the code by specifying in same GridScrollSettingsBuilder as the height.